Virtual IP setup on two VMs using pacemaker
Do we need 3 VMs to set up pacemaker virtual IP to maintain quorum?
I currently have two VMs running Postgres bi-directional replication. I want to create one IP address for communication. How to setup this using Pacemaker.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can set up a pacemaker cluster with only two nodes. This is addressed in various online articles, such as 1 and 2 (I think the first one exactly addresses your use case).
You will need to have a valid fencing configuration for this to work correctly; if you're using virtual machines, then fence_virt may be the best choice.
However, if your goal is simply to have a virtual ip that will migrate between the two systems in the event of a failure, consider keepalived instead, which is much simpler to work with than pacemaker.
